# How do blue shifts in Raman spectra indicate a co-crystalline compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, mixtures, crystallography, raman

The short conference paper [The Acetylene-Butane Co-Crystal: A Potentially Abundant Molecular Mineral on Titan](https://agu.confex.com/agu/abscicon19/meetingapp.cgi/Paper/480183) (mentioned in EurekaAlert's ['Bathtub rings' around Titan's lakes might be made of alien crystals](https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2019-06/agu-ra062319.php)) says:

> **Experimental:** Acetylene (purified to remove acetone stabilizer) and butane (99% purity) were condensed into a liquid nitrogen-cooled cryostage (Linkam Scientific Instruments Ltd.) at 90 K or 130 K. Raman spectra within the cryostage were obtained using a high-resolution confocal dispersive micro- Raman spectrometer (Horiba Jobin Yvon LabRam HR) equipped with a 50 mW Nd:YAG laser (frequency- doubled 532 nm) as the excitation source. Thermal stability studies were performed by warming in 5 or 10 K increments and obtaining Raman spectra following a 5-minute equilibration time.
>
> **Results:** Blue shifts (12–29 cm-1) of the C≡C and C-H stretching modes indicate the formation of a co-crystalline compound. We observed similar shifts for co-crystals comprised of benzene and ethane (2–12 cm- 1 red shifts; Vu et al. 2014) and of acetylene and ammonia (7–16 cm-1 red shifts; 42–66 cm-1 blue shifts; Cable et al. 2018). These shifts indicate a change in the chemical environment of the molecular species, typically modification of a host crystal lattice to accommodate a guest molecule.

**Question:** Is it common to conclude that such blue shifts in Raman spectra "...indicate the formation of a co-crystalline compound"? There is a solid with both molecules in close contact so they interact, but how does this point specifically to there being  a o-crystalline compound?

Comment: No. Those are the results of a specific case. They could have said "Red shift (12-29 cm^-1....) and I would have kept reading without wondering. Indeed, this is the case for the benzene-ethane sample. Also, confocal microraman is a microscope, allowing to spatially resolve the spectroscopic features. That is what probably points to co-crystallisation, i.e.  no or little segregation of phases.